# C# Socket connection to server app with unknown IP

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, client-server

I was wondering how one would connect to a server app if you know nothing more than that it is running on the same network? The typical socket connection requires an IP address in order to connect, but what if its unknown? Is there some other way to either connect without an IP or determine the server app's IP somehow?

I'm asking this because to me it seems quite impractical to have to hard code the server IP into the client app, or have the user manually type it in at run time? When you are on a network where IPs automatically get assigned by DHCP server, you will never know for sure what IP the server app is running on unless you give that machine a static IP, something that I want to avoid.

I hope my inquiry is clear enough.

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            socket.Connect(serverIP, serverPort); <- this line is what I want and alternate to
            client = new TGHClient(socket);
            client.Received += client_Received;
            client.Disconnected += client_Disconnected;

        }
```

Comment: You could store the IP (or host name and look the IP up) as part of your configuration settings?

Comment: connect to the server using it's name given by the DNS server. you can resolve connection with DNS or IP. Calling by name will query the DNS server that will return the current IP and you will connect to the proper server correctly. You can also always retrieve these settings from a local setting/XML/ini file

Comment: Thanks, for the feedback. I don't want to have to save any form of config file on the client side. The server app has a DB with config settings. The client app retrieves this when it connects for the first time. Establishing that connection is the tricky part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an UDP broadcast.

The server would have to listen to a UDP port, and reply to broadcasts on this port.

A client would first broadcast a packet for this UDP port, and wait for reply.

The reply would contain the IP address and any information the client would need to use the server.

After this initial UDP communication a regular TCP connection can be established.

Comment: This sounds promising, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: just a note the reply will need to send the port a as well so a response like IP_Address:port is good.

Comment: That's right and it is why I wrote "and any information the client would need to use the server."